# How can I test a Controller with @WebMvcTest, MockMvc and OAuth Security

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, junit5

I have an Spring Boot 2.4.5 project with Kotlin created using this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-b2c-oidc)

```
src/
├── main/
│   └── kotlin/
│       └── de.mbur.myapp/
│           ├── controller/
│           │   └── WebController.kt
│           ├── security/
│           │   └── WebSecurityConfiguration.kt
│           └── MyApplication.kt
└── test/
    └── kotlin/
        └── de.mbur.myapp/
            ├── controller/
            │   └── WebControllerTest.kt
            ├── security/
            └── MyApplicationTests.kt
```

Security Config:

```kotlin
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfiguration(private val configurer: AADB2COidcLoginConfigurer) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

  override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .apply(configurer)
  }
}
```

Controller:

```kotlin
@Controller
class WebController {
  private fun initializeModel(model: Model, token: OAuth2AuthenticationToken?) {
    if (token != null) {
      val user = token.principal
      model.addAllAttributes(user.attributes)
      model.addAttribute("grant_type", user.authorities)
      model.addAttribute("name", user.name)
    }
  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  fun index(model: Model, token: OAuth2AuthenticationToken?): String {
    initializeModel(model, token)
    return "home"
  }

}
```

And finally the test:

```kotlin
@WebMvcTest(WebController::class)
internal class WebControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

  @MockBean
  private lateinit var configurer: AADB2COidcLoginConfigurer

  @Test
  fun testWebController() {
    mockMvc
      .perform(get("/"))
      .andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isForbidden)
  }

  @Test
  @WithMockUser
  fun testAuthentication() {
    mockMvc
      .perform(get("/"))
      .andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isOk)
  }

}
```

First I have to mention that I had to mock the `AADB2COidcLoginConfigurer` to make the test `testWebController` run at all.

Then I tried to run the second test with the `@WithMockUser` annotation as I now it from classical spring security tests. But that did not work:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current user principal is not of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken]: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
```

How can I run this test similar to Spring username password security when `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` is expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the [`RequestPostProcessors`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#testing-oauth2-login) provided by Spring Security.

```
fun testAuthentication() {
    mockMvc
      .perform(get("/")
            .with(oauth2Login())
      .andExpect(status().isOk)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, that I found and adapted to my use-case is this:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContext

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockOAuth2SecurityContextFactory::class)
annotation class WithMockOAuth2
```

```kotlin
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcIdToken
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextFactory


class WithMockOAuth2SecurityContextFactory : WithSecurityContextFactory<WithMockOAuth2?> {

  override fun createSecurityContext(mockOAuth2: WithMockOAuth2?): SecurityContext {
    val context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext()
    if (mockOAuth2 != null) {
      val authorities = null
      val idToken = OidcIdToken
        .withTokenValue("test")
        .claim("sub", "test")
        .build()
      val principal = DefaultOidcUser(authorities, idToken)
      val auth = OAuth2AuthenticationToken(principal, authorities, "test")
      context.authentication = auth
    }
    return context
  }
}
```

```kotlin
  @Test
  @WithMockOAuth2
  fun testAuthentication() {
    mockMvc
```

But the other one is shorter and works fine...

This one may be more flexible if one needs to test specific roles, scopes or names...